# Reason to put "& 511" with file permission

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions

I found a piece of code

```
$permission = fileperms(constant("ABSPATH") . "/wp-login.php") & 511;
```

But I am not understanding why & 511 is putted there.

Can someone explain what's meant by "&" here and also altogether "& 511" with file permission.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79020/bitwise-operators-for-permissions